# XSLT foreach loop

Tags: xslt, variables, foreach

I have only been introduced to xslt and xml in the last few weeks, and I urgently need some help to write some code to achieve what I want to achieve.
I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc1 formName="Form">
    <Level1>
        <Element1>ZZZ</Element1>
        <Element2>
            <SubElement1>Apples</SubElement1>
            <SubElement2>Oranges</SubElement2>
            <SubElement3>Pears</SubElement3>
            <SubElement4>Blueberries</SubElement4>
            <SubElement5>Milkshakes</SubElement5>
        </Element2>
    </Level1>
    <Level1>
        <Element1>XXX</Element1>
        <Element2>
            <SubElement1>Apples</SubElement1>
            <SubElement2>Oranges</SubElement2>
            <SubElement3>Kiwifruit</SubElement3>
            <SubElement4>Blueberries</SubElement4>
            <SubElement5>Soda</SubElement5>
        </Element2>
    </Level1>
</abc1>
```

and the following html table:

```
<table>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 1</td>
    <td width="540" colspan="4"> Cell_A</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Types</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 1</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 2</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 3</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Row 2</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_B</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_C</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_D</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 3</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_E</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_F</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_G</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Row 4</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_H</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_I</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_J</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 5</td>
    <td width="540" colspan="4"> Cell_K</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am having trouble using xslt to extract the data from the xml into the table because the rules that I need to apply make it very complicated. Below are the rules that need to apply to the cells that I am having troubles with.

(1) If the `<Element1>` value is the same throughout the xml, then:

If `<Element1>` = 'ZZZ' then Cell_B = '10', Cell_C = '20', and Cell_D = '30'

If `<Element1>` = 'XXX' then Cell_B = '100', Cell_C = '90', and Cell_D = '80'

but if the `<Element1>` value differs in the xml, then:

Cell_B = '10,100', Cell_C = '20,90', and Cell_D = '30,80'

(2) If the `<SubElement5>` value is the same throughout the xml, then:

Cell_J = the value of `<SubElement5>`

but if the `<SubElement5>` value differs in the xml, then:

Cell_J = the value of both `<SubElement5>` values separated by a comma

so in this case, the value for Cell_J would be  'Milkshakes, Soda'.

I have been experimenting with different things using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Level1/Element2">
<xsl:value-of select="./SubElement5"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but I cant determine what code I can use to check if they are the same because I can't overwrite the value of a variable.

**Edit:** 
Please note that the cells I've indicated above (cells b,c,d, and j) are the only ones I
need help with. Additionally, for `Element1` there are four potential values I can 
encounter: ZZZ, XXX, AAA, and BBB. The required values for each of these would be:
(cells b,c, and d)

```
ZZZ:10,20,30
XXX:100,90,80
AAA:40,30,30
BBB:50,30,20
```

so if there was only one potential value in the whole xml, the cells should appear with the values as above. If the two element 1 values are different, then the cells should list the above values in each cell, separated by a comma.

With respect to cell_j, I'll try and explain it a little better.

First, I need to determine if `<SubElement5>` is the same value throughout the xml. In this case it is not, in one section it is Milkshakes and in the other it is 'Soda'. Therefore, cell_J should contain the text 'Milkshakes, Soda'.

If the xml looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <abc1 formName="Form">
        <Level1>
            <Element1>ZZZ</Element1>
            <Element2>
                <SubElement1>Apples</SubElement1>
                <SubElement2>Oranges</SubElement2>
                <SubElement3>Pears</SubElement3>
                <SubElement4>Blueberries</SubElement4>
                <SubElement5>Milkshakes</SubElement5>
            </Element2>
        </Level1>
        <Level1>
            <Element1>XXX</Element1>
            <Element2>
                <SubElement1>Apples</SubElement1>
                <SubElement2>Oranges</SubElement2>
                <SubElement3>Kiwifruit</SubElement3>
                <SubElement4>Blueberries</SubElement4>
                <SubElement5>Milkshakes</SubElement5>
            </Element2>
        </Level1>
    </abc1>
```

Then the value for cell_j would just be 'Milkshakes'.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

**ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION:**

To Summarize what Woody did below for anybody's future reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/abc1">
           <xsl:variable name="elements" select="//Element1[not(preceding::Element1 = .)]"/>
<table>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 1</td>
    <td width="540" colspan="4"> Cell_A</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Types</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 1</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 2</td>
    <td width="180" >Type 3</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Row 2</td>
    <td width="180" > <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">40</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">50</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">100</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">10</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each></td>
    <td width="180" ><xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">90</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">20</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each></td>
    <td width="180" ><xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">20</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">80</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">30</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 3</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_E</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_F</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_G</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" >Row 4</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_H</td>
    <td width="180" >Cell_I</td>
    <td width="180" ><xsl:for-each select="//SubElement5[not(preceding::SubElement5/text() = text())]">
       <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td width="180" > Row 5</td>
    <td width="540" colspan="4"> Cell_K</td>
</tr>
</table>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Woody, thank-you again. This was awesome.

Comment: You forgot to specify what goes into cells E, F, G, H and I. Please *edit* the question and provide the missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe key with your problem is that you can't itterate through the data to get what you want, as the answers you want are fixed, ie, if this, output that, if that, output this other. So you need to take each section at a time.

Are there only ever two Level1s?

```
        <xsl:template match="/abc1">
            <table>
                <tr> 
                    <td width="180" >Row 2</td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(Level1/Element1='XXX')">
                    <!-- only ZZZ -->
                        <td width="180" >10</td>
                        <td width="180" >20</td>
                        <td width="180" >30</td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(Level1/Element1='ZZZ')">
                    <!-- only YYY -->
                        <td width="180" >100</td>
                        <td width="180" >90</td>
                        <td width="180" >80</td>   
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- some combination -->
                        <td width="180" >10,100</td>
                        <td width="180" >20,90</td>
                        <td width="180" >30,80</td>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </tr>
                .. continued
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and so on per section. If you have a number of rows, and you want them comma separated then you need to do it per section
or if you have to put one comma list for each section.

Sorry, I couldn't see what you were trying to do with the cell_j and there didn't seem to be a rule for the other ones

Edit: However, if you have a lot of items rather than just 2, and you need a comma separated list, you can do it with xpath, so:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="//SubElement5[not(preceding::SubElement5/text() = text())]">
       <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </td>
  .. maybe other rows the same
</tr>
```

Edit again:

So for your updated question about cell_j, the above comes up with the correct values for it.

For your update in the first section, it would be possible to do a variation on that same theme, if you want all the values shown (so there are 4 values if you have all of your 4 options). Unfortunately as you have fixed values for each, and you have to do each one by one, you would need to do it in a large section, so in a loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Element1[not(preceding::Element1/text() = text())]">
```

which would put you in a loop for each unique entry and then have a choose element based on whether that value was XXX, ZZZ etc.

**Edit again**

There are several ways of doing the first section you want, including recursive functions, external documents and using the node-set function of various different XSLT implimentations, but as a totally generic easy to see way, this is the slightly wordy, but easy to see version (I hope):

```
<xsl:variable name="elements" select="//Element1[not(preceding::Element1 = .)]"/>
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td width="180" >Row 2</td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">40</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">50</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">100</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">10</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">90</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">20</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'AAA'">30</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'BBB'">20</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'XXX'">80</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'ZZZ'">30</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

actually - I am not sure if the iterating on a variable ($elements in this case) is that standard, it may be a saxon and msxsl thing, but if it isn't, you can replace it with the value (//Element1[not(preceding::Element1 = .)])

Comment: Thank-you for your help. To answer your questions I will add some additional information to my original post.

Comment: Thank you again. Could you please expand on the last section <xsl:for-each select="//Element1[not(preceding::Element1/text() = text())]"> with an example? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that because once you have established which unique elements you have, you have to put them in each <td>, you have to do the test 3 times, once for each td, as there is no way of storing the value and carying on, to print the values. So even though you do a test and find that say ZZZ is present, and you know all 3 values from all tds, you have to complete the first td before starting the second. I haven't got a chance to write it down at the moment, will do it in a few hours if you still need it

Comment: Thanks Woody. I would really appreciate it if you could write it down. I will give it a go myself though and see if I can figure out exactly what you mean. Thank-you so much.